# Interpreting the QDA discriminant function

Tags: machine-learning, discriminant-analysis

In the QDA discriminant function, what do the 'T's represent? What does $x^T$ mean?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is the transpose operation. Here $x$ stands for a column vector, hence $x^T$ is the same vector but represented as a row instead of a column